# (saxon dtd)java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file fromserver

Tags: java, dtd, saxon, socketexception

I use Saxon(Java) to convert `*.xhtml` to `*.xml`.

Here is my java code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory","net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
System.out.println("load xslt file");
Templates templates = tfactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xsltFile));

Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
Result result = new StreamResult(new File(filtTempXml));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFile), result);
```

Because there is DTD in the `*.xhtml` file, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The error:

```
 java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

I want to know:

1) How to simply disable the dtd?

2) If not, how to set catalog file(mapping dtd to local) for saxon in Java program? Any example?

Thanks.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572808/java-xml-xslt-prevent-dtd-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I know how to implement it.

```
SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

EntityResolver entityReolver = new EntityResolver() {
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Entity resolving systemID... " + publicId);
        if (systemId.indexOf((".dtd")) != -1) {
            System.out.println("Entity Resolved...");
            return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>".getBytes()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
    }
};
xmlReader.setEntityResolver(entityReolver);

SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(xmlReader, SAXSource.sourceToInputSource(new   StreamSource(xmlFile)));
transformer.transform(saxSource, result);
```